intel_pstate, scaling_driver and scaling_governor (battery-save)
I have a i9-12900H with optimus enabled (3080ti mobile) ...
i have set onto kernel parameter this:
intel_pstate=passive,hwp_only,support_acpi_ppc
after included in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= line, i have run update-grub and reboot ...
Now, i cat 2 (two) files:
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
and
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
I got intel_pstate to the former and powersave for the last ...
I have noticed a good battery save using an external monitor connected to intel. About 8 hours.
I would like to know with i can have multiple options with intel_pstate like i did...
I am on ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
Thx

What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?

@DavidDE Hi David, i am on ubuntu 24.04 LTS. the kernel-parameters.txt from admin guide do not mention nothing about more than one option with intel_pstate. I opened YouTube, Spotify and other apps, connected on external (intel) monitor and my battery is almost 8:30 hrs. My preset is right? or this is a placebo. Anyone else can help test?

@DavidDE None performance penalty connected to ac power ...

The intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver is not in passive mode, because it would report intel_cpufreq as the driver if it was. I've only ever done it one parameter at a time, i.e. intel_pstate=passive intel_pstate=no_hwp
